# Express js image referer undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to get the url of the website asking for an image from an express server.

```
var express = require('express')
  , app     = express();

app.get('/image', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers.referer || req.headers.referrer);
  res.sendFile('image.jpg', {root: './public'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I go to a website, and change the `src` of an image to `http://localhost:3000/image` I get on the console the url of the page asking for the image. and sometimes I get `undefined`.

Is it normal ? is there a way I can always get the url of the website from where the image was loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is normal,
because the referrer field is an optional part of the HTTP request sent by the web browser to the web server. And also referrer information can violate privacy, therefore some web browsers allow the user to disable the sending of referrer information.

Comment: which means there is no way I always get the domain of the website loading my image ?

Comment: I think, you can only identify user by cookies or tokens. You can prevent some domains by cors. But nothing more. of course You can use referer but it can be empty or even modified (then you receive wrong referer), therefore it is good as addictional info but nothing more